# MonoTouch for iPad: How to hookup a subcontrol UITableView with a custom UITableViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitableview

This is an iPad app. I have a UIViewController that has two UITableView on it (among other views). What I try to do is to create a custom UITableViewController for each of those UITableViews. How do I hook them up? Is it possible? How do I do it using MonoTouch? or did I misunderstand the whole concept?

Comment: Not sure this is relevant, but I had to show one view inside another, and just dropped a SubView onto the main view. Then, from code I constructed an instance of the controller for the view I intended to show there, and used `controller.View` to get hold of the view object, and added that inside the SubView control I added to the main view. This way I had an object instance for that controller *before* the subview. But, I'm new to MonoTouch, so I'm in no way certain this was the right/best/only way to do this.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use UITableViewController? We just use the UITableViews in our app and haven't found a need for controllers yet. If you do, I would recommend looking at this article: http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/monotouch-controllers-by-example/uitableviewcontroller-by-example.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your link, competent_tech. After reading the recommended article, I think I got an idea how to do it now.

Comment: This are some good stuff I found very helpful: http://www.infoq.com/articles/monotouch-custom-tables. http://sabonrai.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/monotouch-sample-code-uitableview/